# SQL запрос ничего не возвращает. Почему?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать выборку по дате, но sql запрос ничего не возвращает

Записываю в базу:

```
public void addCoordinates() {
    addTimeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat addDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    addDate = addDayFormat.format(addTimeCalendar.getTime());
    SQL sqlHelper = new SQL(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in coordinates: ---");
    cv.put("Latitude", latitude);
    cv.put("Longitude", longitude);
    cv.put("Time", addDate);
    long rowID = db.insert("coordinates", null, cv);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
    db.close();
    sqlHelper.close();
}
```

Пытаюсь получить:

```
public void showTrackByDate() {
        SQL sqlHelper = new SQL(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        double lat, lng;
        String day;
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        LatLng dbCoordinates;

        addTimeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat addDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String nowDate = addDayFormat.format(addTimeCalendar.getTime());

        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM coordinates WHERE Time = " + nowDate, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            lat = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Latitude")));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Longitude")));
            day = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Time"));
            dbCoordinates = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            polylineOptions
                    .add(dbCoordinates)
                    .color(Color.BLACK)
                    .width(2)
                    .geodesic(true);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location)).position(dbCoordinates));
            map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
        }
        c.close();
        sqlHelper.close();
        db.close();
}
```

Если запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT *FROM coordinates
```

То все выводится. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В базе дата хранится как дата или как текст?

Comment: это база SQLite, как string

Comment: а почему значение даты не экранировано в запросе, типа  c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM coordinates WHERE Time = '" + nowDate + "'", null);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте экранировать значение даты в запросе:

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM coordinates WHERE Time = '" + nowDate + "'", null);
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!
забыл совсем про экранирование